# Disable html select when sending form

Tags: jquery, html

When I send my form and in one of the select box nothing is selected I do not want this element to be sent to the server. So I use jquery to disable it.

```
$('#selectYear').prop('disabled', true);
```

But unfortunately, it still gets sent to the server as `year=null` in the query string. But instead, it should not be sent at all because on the server it will be received as `year = "null"`. So I thought when disabling it everything will be fine but, instead, it gets sent as null which I do not want.

Comment: Please show your HTML code and full JS/JQ code. Is ``#selectYear`` a ``<select>`` or some other HTML tag? One suggestion would be to use jQuery to remove the ``name`` attribute so it won't get transmitted with the rest of the form fields.

Comment: By default, disabled controls will not be included - so it depends on *how* you're generating your post.

Comment: Can you show the code that is posting the data to the server please

Comment: The problem could be that I use $('#btnSubmit').trigger('click'); to submit the form. But I am really confused now because yeah when an element is disabled it should not be sent at all when sending a form. I have this problem the first time as well.

Comment: maybe it is also a spring problem. I just saw that when I open developer menu and look at the form data it is not present, but somehow in my controller it comes in as "null" instead of null which is strange. So it seems to be more a spring issue

Comment: There's no mention of "spring" in your question - can you add the correct tag please?

Comment: Yeah I did. What I also found out. When a combo Box is empty it is not sent at all. So when combo box is empty no need to disable it !!!!

Comment: guys I think I solved the issue. It is my own fault. I redirect the incoming form and do not check for null and then null will get "null" . But really thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` to make and element *"act disabled"*, easier way then having to add `disabled` to every element.

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('my_form').classList.add('disable');
}
```

```css
.disable {
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <form id="my_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />

    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />

    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <button id="button">
  Disable
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you set the disabled prop, before the form is submitted:

```
function checkSelectYear(){    
  if( !$('#selectYear').val() && $('#selectYear').prop('disabled') === "undefined") {    
    $('#selectYear').prop('disabled', true);
    checkSelectYear();
  }
  else{
    $('#myform').submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: @NishalK.R four-year-old question?  Did I miss something?

Comment: @NishalK.R thanks for your welcome. But it looks like a new question for me, as everything else here ;)

Comment: Looks like @NishalK.R used a copy and paste stock response.  There certainly aren't 16+ other answers.